Proof and intuition for $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}(n-k) = \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!} - n$
As the title suggests, I wish to see if there is a proof and/or intuitive explanation for the identity
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}(n-k) = \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!} - n$$
Additionally, is there a similar identity for
$$\sum_{k = n}^\infty\frac{n^k}{k!}(k - n)$$
which I presume will be based on similar derivation and/or intuition.

This identity came up when I attempted to prove Stirling's approximation by applying CLT on a sum of i.i.d. $Poisson(1)$ random variables. I've already shown $\mathbb{E}|\sqrt{n}(\frac{S_n}{n} - 1)| \to \mathbb{E}Z$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. However, I could not compute the expectation on the left and arrive at a closed form solution, which is basically the sum at hand.
Many solutions have been posted, but they all skipped the derivation of this summation identity.

Are you sure about the identity? I think it sums to $\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}-n$. Also the infinite sum you are looking for is $n$.

@HackR You are right. I've edited the question. Thanks!

This is just a telescopic summation where almost all terms (except first and last) cancel out:
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}(n-k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!} = 
$$
$$
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} =
\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!} - n.
$$

Thank you! Do you know if there is a similar identity for the sum from $n$ to $\infty$?

The telescoping idea of Virtuoz also gives you your infinite sum. You have \begin{align*}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}&=\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}\\&= \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!}-}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}\\&= \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}\\&=n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^k(k-n)}{k!}\\&=n-\left(n-\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}\right)\\&=\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}\end{align*}
I will leave the convergence checking to you.
